# Is 当做 and 看做 a synonym or not a synonym?

Tags: meaning, usage, word

Is 当做 and 看做 a synonym? I looked at a few sample sentences on bkrs dictionary. They seem to be used in similar situations. But just to be sure, what do you guys think? Do they have any difference in certain situations?

Answer (score 2):

In traditional Chinese used in Taiwan, 當作 can be used when you use something or treat something as if it's something else. For example:

> 他把你當作奴隸在使喚。
> He ordered you around as if you are slave.
>
> 他把球棒當作武器用。
> He used a bat as a weapon.

Whereas 看作 can be used when you recognize something as something else.

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks! Oh btw i noticed you wrote the character as 當作 and 看作. Is 當作 and 看作 the same as 当做 and 看做?

Comment: @Nephilim I used traditional Chinese. 當 can be written as 当 when you written as simplified Chinese(mainly used in China). 當 is traditional Chinese. 当 is simplified Chinese.

Answer (score 2):

Question:- Is 当做 and 看做 a synonym?

The short answer is no, the long answer is the differentiation is quite subtle that if one is used for the other, some people would not actually notice or object, hence your question?

BTW, it has also been written as 当作 & 看作 which may be considered arguably more acceptable / correct. Perhaps for another question?

Coming to the question, OOO has already given an answer / examples for 当做, i.e., to use some other thing "in place of" what is normally / commonly used for a certain purpose.

The latter 看做 or 看作,  is "to regard / recognize / treat", (whether deliberately or mistakenly), one thing / behavior / attitude for some other.

E.g. 不要以我的宽容看做弱点。

Do not regard my tolerance as a weakness.

Comment: It seems you have [two accounts](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/users/23160/wayne-cheah) now, which appears to be due to registering recently.  I think diamond moderators can merge these two accounts, if you like.

Comment: Yes,  it appears so as I did a "second" registration when the system prompted me to complete my registration. Kindly merge them. Thank you very much.

Comment: Good answer. In 不要以我的宽容看做弱点, the use of 以 is a bit off. 不要把我的宽容看做弱点 is more accurate.

Comment: Dan - Yes, upon reflection, you are right. I was using 以 as shorthand for 以 为, and after your comment and re-reading the sentence again, 把 is more compatible as  以 为 would require the sentence to read as " 不要以为我的宽容表达弱点“ -- “Do not think that my tolerance expresses weakness "

Comment: @WayneCheah Please check [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: songyuanyao -- Thanks. I'll look into it.